# How to run a continuous loop that imports another file? I am using Python and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

My goal is to let a programme run every 30 seconds, however every time that I run the code it stops after executing the code only once...

Currently I have one .py file (named: loop) that includes the loop and in that loop it will import another .py file (named: hello). In my hello file the only code is print('hello').

Every time when I run the code the text hello is printed after 30 seconds, but only once.

When I change the text in the loop file to print('hello') instead of import hello it works perfectly, but as soon as I change it, it doesn't seem to work anymore...

Can anybody explain me why?

The code looks like this:

LOOP FILE:

```
from time import sleep
import schedule
import time

def ap():
    import hello

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(ap)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

HELLO FILE:

```
print('hello')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can import module only once (second time import won't have any effect since module name already added to `sys.modules`), so nothing will be done on second `import hello`. I'd suggest you to define function in module `hello.py`, import it to `loop.py` and then call on each iteration:

HELLO FILE:

```
def print_hello():
    print('hello')
```

LOOP FILE

```
from hello import print_hello

def ap():
    print_hello()
```